# Doctrine Filters: filtering only directly hydrated entities, not relation ones

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-orm-filters

How can I determine (within Doctrine filter) if entity is directly hydrated or was only joined or is fetched from other's entity relation?

I know how can it be filtered globally, this works (filter is enabled in Symfony's `kernel.request` listener):

#### Entities

```php
/**
 * Period
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="period")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\PeriodRepository")
 */
class Period {
    /** 
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="periods")
     */
    private $task;
}

/**
 * Task
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name = "task")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TaskRepository")
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="integer")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Period", mappedBy="task")
     */
    private $periods;
}
```

#### Filter

```php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine\Filter;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Task;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

/**
 * DisableTasksFilter excludes tasks from Doctrine results.
 */
class DisableTasksFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    const NAME = 'acme_disable_tasks';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $entity, $alias)
    {
        // Ignore tasks with type = 1
        if ($entity->getReflectionClass()->name === Task::class) {
            return "$alias.type != 1";
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

### BUT... (THE PROBLEM)

Filter should work only for direct fetching `Task` entities and SHOULD NOT filter `Task` relations in `Period` entities, nor joined entities in queries (it could break some logic).

In our app there are few places where `Task`s are fetched:

- `TaskManager` methods
- `TaskRepository` used in `TaskManager` and directly
- `User->tasks` relation (via helper methods which filter collection with `ArrayCollection::filter()`)
- `Period->task` relation

It would be much easier if it could be possible to filter it with globally registered filter instead of adding conditions to each place where `Task`s are fetched.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I'd try dumping `ClassMetadata`. There might be some clue to detect if it's primary entity.

Comment: @TomášVotruba I've checked all available properties and methods (by names, not by returned results) and couldn't find anything. It's possible to determine if it's root entity, but in entity-inheritance-hierarchy context.

Comment: Another things might be: 1) using event subscriber, 2) using unit of work, 3) looking for "addFilterConstraint" in Doctrine code.
I'd also dig deeper then checking method and properties names. There might be some other hints that could be useful. Also naming is now always helpful, moreover in Doctrine which becomes quiet deprecated in time.